# Java files in netbeans don't open

Tags: java, netbeans

I have strange problem i NetBeans am using Maven.

And when i try open java files i have problem.
File dont open . The screen appers and it's all grey

This looks like this.

http://prntscr.com/6lk6yc

Any know what is happening ?

```
NetBeas Info:
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201411181905)
Updates: Updates available to version NetBeans 8.0.2 Patch 1
Java: 1.8.0_05; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.5-b02
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_05-b13
System: Windows 8 version 6.2 running on amd64; Cp1250; pl_PL (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0
Cache directory: C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot there is a little red circle at `automatictestsmaven` project, that indicates that there are some problems with your project.

Rightclick on the project and select **Properties** (at the bottom) to check where it says there are errors.

Its also odd that some of the files do have the .java file extension but the file icon is blank.

Comment: @user3202747 have you tried recreating the project and add the files to the new project manually? Have you checked if the files contain any lines at all? Have you tried restarting Netbeans?

Comment: @user3202747 i don't know why that blue icon from Maven central repository is there. How did you set up your project?

Comment: SetUp
http://prntscr.com/6ll8ns 
I restart netBeans. I delete and create project couple times. On one computer this works on another doesn't want to. Maybe this is some diffrent problem. Rly i dont meet with something like this.

Comment: Update fix my problems. !